# iphone app: how to deactivate and activate ipod app

Tags: iphone, audiosession

my voip app is configured to kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord category and kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers audio session property.

During voip call, when voice playback and record is happening, ipod music is also mixing with voice.

How to make ipod music to deactive during voice call and re-active after completion of my voice call.

Answer (score 0):

how about following:

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] pause];
```

at the beginning of your voip call and

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] play];
```

at the end of your voip call.